# Cropping a transformed widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Column of 3 Containers, with the middle one transformed by rotating it back a bit.

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Transform(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
        ..rotateX(pi / 3),
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.green,
    )
  ],
),
```

[image]

Since Transform will use the height of its child, the middle item is now left with some top and bottom space. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: I don't think so.. what exactly do you want to use it for? Do you just want the shape of it or what is the reason for you using transform?

Comment: When some condition is true, I want my items in the list to react with this effect, but the top and bottom space need to be removed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I figured out is to use a [SizedOverflowBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedOverflowBox-class.html).

> A widget that is a specific size but passes its original constraints
>   through to its child, which may then overflow.

By using this, the Column will think that the middle Container's size is smaller than it actually is.

```
 child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      SizedOverflowBox(
        size: Size(100, cos(pi/3) * 100),
        child: Transform(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
            ..rotateX(pi / 3),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.green,
      )
    ],
  ),
```